# How to apply CSS class to dropdown in Django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I have a form that has two fields who are dropdowns that show objects from other models through a Foreign Key.

```
class NewFlight(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Flight
        fields = ('date', 'flight_id', 'company', 'airport')


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewFlight, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date'].widget = forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'data-target': '#datetimepicker1'})
        self.fields['flight_id'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
```

Both `company` and `airport` are objects from another model.

So, if in the `def __init__` I use the `forms.Select` widget, with the class `form-control`, I'll get the styling correct, but all the dropdown is empty. If I just leave the default form, all the "companies" are correctly displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question: I ended up using [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks)